# What type of pointer should I pass to a method in C++11?

Tags: c++, pointers, smart-pointers

There is two different scenarios I'm after:

1. You have a `shared_ptr`
2. You have a `unique_ptr`

The answer might be the same though.

Consider a method, which uses a pointer but does not assume ownership:

```
void use_pointer(T ptr)
{
    ptr->act();
}
```

Should T be

- `my_type *` (raw pointer)
- `const shared_ptr<my_type> &` (sending const ref, if using shared_ptr)
- `const unique_ptr<my_type> &` (sending const ref, if using unique_ptr)
- `weak_ptr<my_type>` (constructing weak_ptr for method call)

Something else? Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you do not assume ownership, then preferably accept a reference to the pointee. If you want to express optionality, you *can* use a raw pointer, or you can use e.g. `boost::optional<U&>` (where `U` is the pointee type).

Functions that do no assume ownership should almost never accept a smart pointer. There is in general nothing useful for the callee in a smart pointer interface other than means of getting to the pointee. So pass that instead.

Comment: Conveniently, if you accept a reference, the calling syntax is the same for all pointer types: `use_pointer(*ptr)`

Answer (score 5):

Let the caller decide:

```
template<typename T>
void use_pointer(const T& ptr)
{
    ptr->act();
}
```

Works nicely with raw pointers (if the caller has, for example, an array with automatic or static lifetime), `shared_ptr`, `unique_ptr`, and also all kinds of iterator types if the caller is passing you one element from a collection.

Comment: This is a good idea, and actually thought of it as soon as I wrote the 'placeholder' T in the question... But accepted the other one since this is a bit cumbersome as a general case type of thing.

Comment: @Max: I really like Luc's solution too -- but only if the argument is a `const` reference.

Answer (score 3):

In this case, it should probably be `my_type&`. If you really have to pass a pointer, then just pass a raw one: since you're using smart pointers in your code, when someone sees a raw one they shouldn't think "oh no, it can leak!" but rather "aha, a non-owning pointer" (that is, assuming they're familiar with idiomatic C++).

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible to answer the question without knowing why you have a
smart pointer (instead of a raw pointer), and without knowing the
semantics of the called function, and in particular, why it needs a
pointer (rather than call by value or by const reference).  As a good
starting point, however: if the function takes a class type, use const
reference, otherwise, use value.  (But is there ever a scenario where
you would have a pointer to something that isn't a class type?)

Answer (score 0):

If the function is going to store the pointer (for example add into a container), use std::shared_ptr, otherwize use std::unique_ptr. If your pointer is already a std::shared_ptr then keep using that.